# Store old data in one column and update new data in another column within same table

Tags: sql, database, asp-classic, sql-update

I'm not a professional programmer but an enthusiast who needs help.  Here is my challenge:

I have a table full of data for our employees.

Currently, any of our employees can go to the "Update" web page on our web site and type in his **new** last name over the **previous** one that is displayed in a textbox and click submit, his last name will be updated in the database.  However, my supervisor wants to keep the employees' **previous** last name in the same table as the **new** last name.  Her idea is when an employee types in his **new** last name in the textbox, it will trigger the database to store his **previous** last name in a column called "Alias" and then update his **new** last name in the "LastName" column.  How do I proceed with that?

Here is the structure of the table:

```
PeopleID (int)  
JobIDNum (int)  
EmployeeIDNum (varchar(25))  
Email (varchar(100))  
Password (varchar(50))  
LastName (varchar(50))  
FirstName (varchar(25))  
Deleted (char(1))  
Alias (varchar(50))
```

I appreciate any assistance and/or advice I can get.

Comment: You can use an UPDATE trigger to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
  SET Alias = LastName, LastName = @LastName 
WHERE PeopleID = @PeopleID
```

Where the `@LastName` is a parameter with **new** value, `@PeopleID` is a id of corresponding people.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest a stored procedure that you can call from ASP.

```
 CREATE PROC UpdateEmp
    @EmpID  int,
    @LastName varchar(50),
    --all the others properties you need to update this person
 AS
 BEGIN

     UPDATE Employee
     SET Alias = LastName,
         LastName = @LastName,
         --all the other properties you want updated.
     WHERE PeopleID = @EmpID;

 END
```

Call this stored proc in your ASP code like this:

```
Dim cmd
Dim ln
Dim retCount    
Dim conn
Set conn= Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")       
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")      
conn.Open "some connection string"
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .Commandtext = "UpdateEmp"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@EmpID", adInteger, adParamInput, 10)
    .Parameters("@EmpID") = 22 'some Employee you get from your code
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@LastName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)
    .Parameters("@LastName") = "MyLastName" 'some Employee you get from your code
    .Execute ln, , adExecuteNoRecords
End With        
Set cmd = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  My work place still uses Classic ASP so I need to change the ASP code a little.

Comment: When I checked the syntax for the Stored Procedure, it says "Error 156: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.  Any idea why?  Thanks!

Comment: Meng : it's the comma after LastName varchar(50)

Comment: The syntax has passed - thank you!  When I run the code, the page shows up "Procedure 'UpdateEmployee' expects parameter '@PeopleID', which was not supplied."  What did I do wrong?  Pardon my ignorance, I'm new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this update statement:

```
UPDATE Employee
Set LastName = @NewLastName,
    Alias = LastName
WHERE PeopleId = @Whatever
```