# Able to Update New Data in One Column But Not Able to Store Old Data in Another

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I posted a question 4 months ago at [[Store old data in one column and update new data in another column within same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336786/store-old-data-in-one-column-and-update-new-data-in-another-column-within-same-t/9131237#9131237)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336786/store-old-data-in-one-column-and-update-new-data-in-another-column-within-same-t/9131237#9131237).

Now, I'm working on the codes again and here is my problem.  After I clicked the "Update" button on the web page, the **old** (previous) LastName did not store in the **Alias** column. In fact, the **new** LastName is stored in both **LastName** (for new LastName) and **Alias** (supposedly for previous LastName) columns. I need the **old** LastName to be kept in the **Alias** column. Please review below and see what I did wrong. Thanks in advance!

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[KeepAliasName]
@PeopleID int,
@LastName varchar(25)

AS BEGIN

UPDATE People
SET Alias = LastName,
LastName = @LastName

WHERE CAST(PeopleID AS Varchar(25)) = @PeopleID

END
```

**Codes that call the Stored Procedure**

```
Dim oCmd1
Dim ln
Dim retCount

Set oCmd1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set oCmd1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

''' EXECUTE THE COMMAND TO CREATE THE RECORDSET
With oCmd1
.ActiveConnection = Connect
.Commandtext = "KeepAliasName"
.CommandType = adoCmd1StoredProc
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@PeopleID", adInteger, adParamInput, 25)
.Parameters("@PeopleID") = pID 'some Employee you get from your code
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@LastName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 25)
.Parameters("@LastName") = lastnameVal 'some Employee's name you get from your code
.Execute ln, , adExecuteNoRecords
End With

Set oCmd1 = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Well unless there's a Doh moment e.g. setting new last name to old last name, y=th only explanation is the dbms is executing the two sets in reverse order!

Easy to find out though.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[KeepAliasName]
@PeopleID int,
@LastName varchar(25)


AS BEGIN

UPDATE People
SET Alias = LastName

WHERE CAST(PeopleID AS Varchar(25)) = @PeopleID

UPDATE People
SET LastName = @LastName

WHERE CAST(PeopleID AS Varchar(25)) = @PeopleID

END
```

Comment: The db updated the new LastName in both columns again.  Please help.  I'm new to SQL.

Comment: It did? Hmmm, well unless small blue rigellians are playing a joke on you, something else is going on. A trigger maybe? Is is possible this piece of code is being executed twice, the second time with the new name? What happens if you only do the second part. Can you put a check constraint on so LastName = Alias throws an error?

Comment: You are right, I've to create a trigger with AFTER INSERT, DELETE to execute the Stored Procedure.  Thanks, Tony.